# Google place Autocomplete is not working?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, build.gradle, google-places-api

Android google Place autocomplete is working fine in gradle version 3.0.But when i changing the android studio to 3.0 and gradle version 4.0 the Google place autocomplete is not working and its components are not resolving.

For solving this issue I updated the gradle dependency to new one and clean and rebuild the project again but then also its not working. This is the library i used with gradle version 3.0

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.1'
>
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.1'

So please help me for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the latest dependencies (including maps, places and location): Try these out

```
// Google Play Services \\
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'
    //-----------------------\\
```